# Delphi - Loading JPEG and printing outputs as a black square?

Tags: delphi, printing, jpeg

Having some trouble with printing JPEG images via Delphi TCanvas. 
Anywhere between 30-50% of the time the JPEG will print out as a black
square rather than as it should. Have tried changing many settings to see
if there was a particular condition under which it would fail to print but
as of the time of writing nothing has worked and the condition still exists - I am not able to tell when the printout may have a black JPEG or when it will print correctly.

Here is the code I am using to print the JPEG to the Canvas.

```
Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
try
  // initialize image
  //>>imgImage := TImage.Create(Self);
  imgImage := TImage.Create(Application);

  // load image from file
  imgImage.Picture.LoadFromFile(sFileNameAndPath);

  // set width and height to that of loaded image
  ////imgImage.Autosize := true;
  ////Printer.Orientation := poPortrait;
  // Header
  Printer.Canvas.Font.Height := MulDiv(GetDeviceCaps(Printer.Canvas.Handle, LOGPIXELSY), 12, 72);
  Printer.Canvas.Font.Name := 'Courier New';

  // Determine height and width of 1 printer-character
  iDeltaW := Printer.Canvas.TextWidth('X');
  iDeltaH := Printer.Canvas.TextHeight('X');

  // ------------------------------
  // Method #1 - columns and lines
  // ------------------------------
  // what column to printing from
  iFromLeftMargin := iLeft * iDeltaW;

  // what line to print from
  iFromTopOfPage := iTop * iDeltaH;

  // ------------------------------
  // Method #2 - pixels
  // ------------------------------
  iPPW := Printer.PageWidth;
  iPPH := Printer.PageHeight;
  iIPW := imgImage.Picture.Width;

  ePXW := iPPW / iInvImageWidth;   
  ePXH := iPPH / iInvImageHeight;  
  //~//iFromLeftMargin := Ceil(iLeft * pxW);
  //~//iFromTopOfPage  := Ceil(iTop  * pxH);
  iFromLeftMargin := Ceil(iLeft * ePXW);
  iFromTopOfPage  := Ceil(iTop  * ePXH);

  // Set printed bitmap width
  iPrintedImageWidth := MulDiv(iPPW, iIPW, iInvImageWidth);  
  // Set printed bitmap height to maintain aspect ratio
  iPrintedImageHeight := imgImage.Picture.Height * iPrintedImageWidth DIV 
    imgImage.Picture.Width; // maintain aspect ratio of bitmap

  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bitmap.Width  := imgImage.Picture.Width;
    Bitmap.Height := imgImage.Picture.Height;
    Bitmap.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
    Bitmap.IgnorePalette := False;
    // Convert JPEG (GIF, or whatever) to BMP
    Bitmap.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, imgImage.Picture.Graphic);

    // Print Image
    PrintBitmap(Printer.Canvas,
      Rect(iFromLeftMargin, iFromTopOfPage,
           iFromLeftMargin + iPrintedImageWidth,
           iFromTopOfPage  + iPrintedImageHeight),
           Bitmap);
  finally
    // free bitmap memory
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
  // free image memory
  imgImage.Free;
finally
  Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
end;
```

If anyone had any ideas it would be much appreciated!

Regards,
James

EDIT: code for the PrintBitmap method below. I have taken the advice of saving the bitmap to disk to view it as it is being generated and the it is never saved as a black square even when the printed output is a black square. I hope this indicated the problem is in the PrintBitmap code below.

```
procedure PrintBitmap(Canvas: TCanvas; DestRect: TRect; Bitmap: TBitmap);
var
  BitmapHeader: pBitmapInfo;
  BitmapImage: POINTER;
  HeaderSize: DWORD;
  ImageSize: DWORD;
begin
  GetDIBSizes(Bitmap.Handle, HeaderSize, ImageSize);
  GetMem(BitmapHeader, HeaderSize);
  GetMem(BitmapImage,  ImageSize);
  try
    GetDIB(Bitmap.Handle, Bitmap.Palette, BitmapHeader^, BitmapImage^);
    StretchDIBits(Canvas.Handle,
              DestRect.Left, DestRect.Top,     // Destination Origin
              DestRect.Right  - DestRect.Left, // Destination Width
              DestRect.Bottom - DestRect.Top,  // Destination Height
              0, 0,                            // Source Origin
              Bitmap.Width, Bitmap.Height,     // Source Width & Height
              BitmapImage,
              TBitmapInfo(BitmapHeader^),
              DIB_RGB_COLORS,
              SRCCOPY);
  finally
    FreeMem(BitmapHeader);
    FreeMem(BitmapImage);
  end;
end; {PrintBitmap}
```

Unfortunately this code was written by someone who no longer works at my company and I am only trying to fix an existing issue.

Comment: Please take the time to properly format your code. Don't use tab characters; indent starting with four space characters, and add additional spaces as needed for indentation. (You can preview your post in real time as you enter it by looking immediately below where you're entering your question so you can see what the formatting looks like to make it easier.) Formatting it when you post not only saves others from having to do so, but also makes it more readable so you stand a better chance of getting an answer quickly. :)

Comment: Is this a multi-threaded application? Also, is it always the same jpg files that fail? I ask this as I have had a similiar problem is the past as the VCL is not thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks for that Ken sorry for the carelessness. Hi Steve - no its just single-threaded and does happen on different jpeg files but not all.

Comment: You might try saving the bitmap to disk, that way you will be able to tell whether it is the jpeg to bitmap conversion that is giving the problem or whether it is the printing of the bitmap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell with the snippet you posted. You should post some self sufficient working code (compilable and runnable).
There is no local var declaration for instance, no Begindoc/EndDoc.

Now, after adding the local declarations, there is a bunch of compiler warnings for *Uninitialized Variables* like `iTop` or `iLeft`. If those are left with random garbage, it could be that you don't draw where you think you do.

You also assume that you always have a `pf24bit` format which is not guaranteed at all. As you don't specify if the same JPG can print OK or fail randomly, or if it is with different JPGs that you have problems, format conversion problems cannot be excluded.

I would also suggest that you install one of the free available Image Debug Visualizers, place a break point before `PrintBitmap` and see if the local `Bitmap` is correct before printing.

Then let us see what is in the `PrintBitmap` procedure... Did you try to directly draw on the Printer Canvas?

Update:
The `PrintBitmap` code seems legit except that it does not check for any return code:

```
if not GetDIB(...) then
  raise [...];
if GDI_ERROR = StretchDIBits(...) then
  RaiseLastOSError;
```

The problem might come from the Printer/Driver.
Did you try with another printer or with another driver?
Also, make sure your printer is ready...

Comment: +1 with a vague question, answers are inevitably speculative. Lots of good suggestions here.

Comment: Yes thanks very much for the excellent suggestions. I have taken the advice of saving and viewing the bitmap image before the print and it is always correct and doesn't appear as a black square in the file. Sorry for the ambiguity of the question, the problem occurs somewhat randomly and the same JPEG can print OK or fail at any given time. Unfortunately the code is poorly written and tightly coupled to other areas of the application so self-sufficient code was hard to come by here.

I have added the PrintBitmap procedure above.

Comment: @François - thanks for the help, I've implemented the extra error checking so hopefully this resolves the issue.